# How can I return an array and HTML data in an AJAX response?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have an array like this in my PHP page named new1.php:

```
$arr = ['value 1', 'value 2', 'value 3'];
$html = '<div>huge data with all tags like a page</div>';
$response = json_encode('array' => $arr, 'html' => $html);
echo $response
```

In the calling page, when I `console.log(data.html)` it gives `undefined`. The same happens for `console.log(data.array);`. Here is my AJAX code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "new1.php",
    type: "POST", 
    data: { somedata: somedata },
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(data.html);
        console.log(data.array);
    }
});
```

Most importantly, I want to know what is the best way to return a page with other data from AJAX response?

Comment: `dataType:"text",` change to  `dataType:"json",`

Comment: @JonStirling, there is no syntax error

Comment: @guradio, if i do so will i be able to get  html page or html content

Comment: @user5405873 There sure as hell was before you updated the question. We can all see the question history...

Comment: I take it back, there are still syntax errors. See `json_encode('array' => $arr, 'html' => $html);`.

Comment: the below answer giving some kind of error like  <b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected '=&gt;' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW) in

Comment: `=>` is for arrays. You probably want `json_encode(['array' => $arr, 'html' => $html]);`, (or use array( ... ) syntax if pre PHP 5.4).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from your php code where you do `json_encode` add this to the top of the page 
 `header("Content-Type: application/json");`
then your encode should take in array as parameter instead

`json_encode(array("array"=>$arr, "html"=>$html));`

it should see your record as **json** now and please change ur dataType to `json`  from Jquery intelligence guess from the server state ([jquery](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)) it will automatically take json instead

> **dataType** (default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html))
>   Type: String
>   The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4 JSON will yield a JavaScript object, in 1.4 script will execute the script, and anything else will be returned as a string). The available types (and the result passed as the first argument to your success callback) are:

Comment: if i do so can i be able to get html page or html content?

Comment: yes, with the data.* format of any content , or now `console.log('my data', data) , it will be logged as json object where you can see the children and their content

Comment: so you dont need to do parse json, when the server is already coming as json already like a .json file. just keep me posted

Comment: i have tried your method but same error  <b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected '=&gt;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127795/discussion-between-theophilus-omoregbee-and-user5405873).

Comment: oh the errror is from your php , please update it to be this instead 
json_encode(array("array"=>$arr, "html"=>$html));

Comment: thanks alot man for your patience and being with me from start

Answer (score 2):

You should be json parse, because you are json encoding from php file, and as there is data type of your ajax is text so you need to parse the json.

```
 $.ajax({
         url:"new1.php",
         type:"POST",
         data:{somedata:somedata},
         dataType:"text",
         success: function(data){
                data = JSON.parse(data);
                  console.log(data);
                console.log(data.html);
                console.log(data.array);

            }
    });
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: it is giving error like <b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected '=&gt;' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW) in

Comment: are you putting exit after :  echo $response ? in php file

Comment: Try by replace php file like : $arr = ['value 1', 'value 2', 'value 3'];
$html = '<div>huge data with all tags like a page</div>';
$response = json_encode('array' => $arr, 'html' => $html);
echo $response exit;

Comment: I've got a bad feeling about this.  Seems like one of those questions where you answer the simple, initial question, and then spend hours answering _"but what about..."_ questions.  Good luck!