# How to populate the div with the response data from Ajax?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I have an Ajax post request which on success returns an array which I would like to load into a div. Now, doing this with single values is quite easy but with an array, I can't seem to find the right way to do it.

```
<fieldset id="div1" ondrop="remove_from_customer(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<legend>Vacant parking spots</legend>
<?php $counter = 0;
echo count(get_free_parking_spots());
foreach (get_free_parking_spots() as $row) { ?>
    <div id="count_id<?php echo $counter; ?>" data-parking_gate="<?php echo $row['parking_gate_id']; ?>" data-location_id="<?php echo $row['location_id']; ?>" data-spot_no="<?php echo $row['spot_no']; ?>" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
        <label><?php echo '' . $row['name'] . '' ?></label>
        <label><?php echo '<p>Gate: ' . $row['parking_gate_id'] . '<p>Spot: ' . $row['spot_no'] . '' ?></label>
    </div>
<?php $counter++;
} ?>
 </fieldset>
 <fieldset id="div2" ondrop="drop_to_customer(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <legend>Current parking spots of the customer</legend>
    <?php $count = 0;
    echo count(get_customer_parking_spots($selected_user_id));
    foreach (get_customer_parking_spots($selected_user_id) as $user) { ?>
        <div id="count_idd<?php echo $count; ?>" data-customerid="<?php echo $user['customer_id']; ?>" data-gate_id="<?php echo $user['gate_id']; ?>" data-spot_id="<?php echo $user['spot_id']; ?>" data-location_id="<?php echo $user['location_id']; ?>" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
            <label><?php echo '' . $user['location_name'] .  '' ?></label>
            <label><?php echo '<p>Gate: ' . $user['gate_id'] . '<p>Spot: ' .  $user['spot_id'] ?></label>
        </div>
    <?php $count++;
    } ?>
</fieldset>
```

**Ajax:**

```
    function drop_to_customer(ev) {           
        if (<?php echo count(get_customer_parking_spots($selected_user_id)); ?> < 3) {
            const el = document.querySelector("[id=" + "\'" + ev.dataTransfer.getData("text") + "\'" + "]");
            
            var add_location = "add location";
            ev.preventDefault();
            var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
            ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));

            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'external_submit.php',
                data: {
                    add_spot: add_location
                },
                success: function(html) {
                    $('#div1').html($('#div1', html).html()); //my failed attempt to reload data into the div here
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

As you can see when `drop_to_customer()` is called I am doing a post request and returning an array which I would like to load into the other div with id `div1`. The array is json_Encoded and it is returned successfully.

**EDIT:**
This is how I echo the array in PHP:

```
echo json_encode(array("array" => get_data($_POST['id']), "html" => $html))
```

Comment: `$('#div1').append($(html));`  ??

Comment: @SimoneRossaini hmmm how can I even check if it's loading the data? As you can see I am doing a count before the foreach loop of the div but that's not going to be replaced with the new data from ajax i guess, right?

Comment: try to use console.log(html) for see response of ajax call back.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini I am receiving the array, thats fine but I just tried to test it if the data is being loaded but it doesn't seem like

Comment: 'loaded' you mean printed?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini sorry, I meant loaded into the div (populating the div with new data)

Comment: so you confirm in `<div id='div1'></div>` simple does not load anything?

Comment: have you see if in console do you have any error? have you a live version?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini I can confirm that it doesn't load the new data into the div but don't worry about the array because it is returning in ajax success, I can assure you that.However, could it be the array format? the one that is being loaded into the div on page load is associative array of arrays but the one returned in ajax is array of objects.

Comment: so i think your answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40525247/how-can-i-return-an-array-and-html-data-in-an-ajax-response)

Comment: @SimoneRossaini thanks that solved the problem partially. Now the returned the array looks better but still its returning an array of objects but this time indexed

Comment: return array is json_Encoded form?

Comment: please success: function(html) {`alert(html);`} what does it return?

Comment: @KUMAR it is returning an array of objects (indexed) and yes it is encoded.  I did same as here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40525247/how-can-i-return-an-array-and-html-data-in-an-ajax-response

Comment: You should be `json parse`, because you are `json encoding` from php file, and as there is data type of your ajax is text so you need to parse the json.

Comment: do success: function(html) {`data = JSON.parse(html); console.log(data);`}

Comment: @KUMAR doesnt work. this is how I echo the array in PHP `echo json_encode(array("array" => get_data($_POST['id']), "html" => $html));`

Comment: @SimoneRossaini maybe I need to do `$('#div1').append($(html))` in the child divs instead of main one? But then the problem would be the id of those divs since they are dynamic.

Comment: can you post how is look the array from html response and your html structure please